# package name clashes with class of same name error in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, package

I was trying out Udacity course on developing android app.[image]

above was the error i ran into when i tried creating an android test case while going through the lesson-4.

the problem is the test classes under the androidtest folderare packaged under
com.sasharma.android.sunshine.testbut whenever i run the app in Androidtest configuration the gradle build the bUildCOnfig File for androidtest with the same package name and gives me the error "**Error:(4, 1) error: package com.sasharma.android.sunshine.test clashes with class of same name"**

Also i found that the only difference between the package names used by course instructors and the one used by me is that they are having an extra "app" to there package names like  my package name for src\main\java*activity classes is also com.sasharma.android.sunshine but theirs is com.sasharma.android.sunshine .test and same goes for the package name under androidTest directory

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a class called `test` or `Test`?

Comment: Also, why don't you respec the Java naming conventions; classes start with an uppercase letter, packages are all-lowercase. And android is spelt `android`, not `andorid`.

Comment: thanks @PeterLawrey  for pointing out the mistake.i had a class name test in one of the packages. it is difficult to find the all the class as i am new to android studio. In eclipse, asimple CTRL+SHIFT+r would have helped me to fetch the class but i dont know the equivalent shortcut in android studio

Answer (score 12):

This is a late answer, but still, none of the answers provided the true reason for why this error is shown.

You get this error when one of your package names are the same as one of your classes, as shown below:

```
main 
    java
        com.yourpackage.mycoolapp
             somePackage
                 myclass.java
                 class2.java
             somePackage.java
```

as you can see above the pack name `somePackage` and the class name `somePackage.java`, has the same name.

---

To fix this you can either change the package name or the name of the class:

**Right click on package/class -> Refactor -> Rename**

Done, no need to rebuild.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the same issue by changing **applicationId** in  `app\build.gradle` and rebuilt the project. My **applicationId** in `build.gradle` was the same as `package` name concatenated with `appname` from `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Before the change:

build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mypackage.MyAppName"
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackage" >
    <application
        android:name="MyAppName"
    </application>
</manifest>
```

After the change:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mypackage.MyApp"
}
```

I had this error in two places:

1. BuildConfig.java in `MyProjectName/app/build/genereted/source/buildConfig/androidTest/debug/mypackage/MyClass/test`
2. R.java in `MyProjectName/app/build/genereted/source/r/androidTest/debug/mypackage/MyClass/test`

both contained `package com.mypackage.MyClass.test;` what was reported had an error.

Answer (score 3):

I try to rebuild the project and solve the problem.

Build->Rebuild Project!

Answer (score 3):

I think you have test.java file in your project files.
Rename it to something else.

```
for android-studio click on test.java and  Go to ReFactor-->Rename
```

Go-to Build-->Rebuild Project.

Answer (score 1):

After the update, I ran into the same error.

1. I deleted the Buildconfig.java
2. Refactor-->Rename, error class.
3. I ran it again solved.

---

```
/AndroidStudioProjects/appName/app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/example/gurkan0791/appName/BuildConfig.java
```

Answer (score 1):

If the Glide library is causing the issue, make sure that the "MyAppGlideModule" class is not an inner class.

Answer (score 0):

You can expect this error also if you define `testApplicationId` same with default one as `yourApplicationId.test`.

As doc [says here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html#change_the_application_id_for_testing):

> By default, the build tools apply an application ID to your instrumentation test APK using the application ID for the given build variant, appended with .test. For example, a test APK for the com.example.myapp.free build variant has the application ID com.example.myapp.free.test.

Hence you should not use same `testApplicationId` as default one by only appending `.test` to your `applicationId`, but you can change it to anything else and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have class of its name is "test" remove it.
i had this problem and reslolve it

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Answer (score 0):

I face this problem when use **EventBus**.

Actually i wrote wrong eventBusIndex and it create file with same package name of my application id and it make error

Wrong code

```
kapt {
    arguments {
        arg('eventBusIndex', 'MY_APPLICATION_ID')//E.g. "com.me.myappname"
    }
}
```

Fixed code

```
kapt {
    arguments {
        arg('eventBusIndex', 'MY_APPLICATION_ID.MyEventBus')//E.g. "com.me.myappname.MyEventBus"
    }
}
```